# How can I display total number of items using count function in a menu layout file in Laravel 7?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 7 to make my application, in mySQL database, I have a table called "projects" which has a column named "status". The statuses are just constants in my Model (status 1,2,3 e.t.c) I would like to display the count of Projects for each status in a menu in my dashboard. How can I achieve this? I have tried to use a Controller but I'm getting an error. My View file is actually a Layout file so I'm sure where is the problem. I'm not so experienced in Laravel. Please help.

In my Controller:

```
class MenuItemsCountController extends Controller
{
    public function getProjectCount()
    {
        $project = Project::where('status','=','1')->count();
        return view('client_panel.layouts.menu',compact('project'));
    }

}
```

My Layout File:

```
<li class="side-menus nav-item dropdown amos-client-menu">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown"><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
            <span>Job Cards</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu side-menus">
            <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/new-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.new-jobcard.index') }}">
                    <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>New</span>
                    <span class="amos-badge">{{count($project)}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/potential-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.potential-jobcard.index') }}">
                        <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Potential</span>
                        <span class="amos-badge">18</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/progress-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.progress-jobcard.index') }}">
                        <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>In Progress</span>
                        <span class="amos-badge">18</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/complete-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.complete-jobcard.index') }}">
                        <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Completed</span>
                        <span class="amos-badge">18</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</li>
```

In my Model:

```
const STATUS_NEW = 1;  
const STATUS_FINISHED = 2;
const STATUS_ONGOING = 3;
const STATUS_POTENTIAL = 4;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Thanks for your response. The View is a Layout file named `menu.blade.php` that I'm using to display a dropdown menu. It's not defined in my web routes file.

Comment: porloscerros Ψ my route is: `Route::get('new-jobcard', 'NewJobCardController@index')->name('client.new-jobcard.index');` The `index.blade.php` extends a layout which I have included the menu using @include.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Alright, thanks for helping, let me try this out.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ I have tried to work on it, I have not found a way of passing `$project` variable to `menu.blade.php` file I'm still getting `undefined variable` error when I click any other link in my application.

Comment: Then you could use a [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers) to that data you want to be bound to the menu view each time that view is rendered

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ, Alright, thanks. let me try it.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Using [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers) has worked very well. Thank you so much.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ, yes, I have edited my question and added the code that I used in AppServiceProvider and in my blade view.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Thanks, I have moved it to answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used View Composer and it worked. In my AppServiceProvider file, I added this code inside the boot() method:

```
public function boot()
    {     
        View::composer('client_panel.layouts.menu', function ($view) {
            $view->with('newprojects', Project::where([
                ['status','=','1'],
                ['created_by','=',Auth::user()->id]
             ])->count());
        });
}
```

Then in blade file I used the variable like this:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">{{$newprojects}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$project = Project::selectRaw("project_name,count(*) as total")
->groupBy('status')
->get();
```

In controller map status to route like below

```
    public function getProjectCount()
    {
       $project = Project::selectRaw("project_name,count(*) as total")
            ->groupBy('status')
            ->get();
       
       $routing=[
            1=>route('client.new-jobcard.index'),
            2=>route('client.potential-jobcard.index')
            
            ];
        
        
       return view('client_panel.layouts.menu',compact('project','routing'));
    }
```

Also make sure to set `'strict' => false,` in database.php for mysql connection

In view you can loop li element.But for routing you can define conditionally set based on status

```
@foreach($project as $key=>$value)
 <li class="side-menus ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ isset($routing[$value->status])?$routing[$value->status]:"#" }}">
                    <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>{{$value->project_name}}</span>
                    <span class="amos-badge">{{$value->total}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your option but I'm still getting `Undefined variable: project` error, what could be the issue?

Comment: i read comment above. in your you need view share or view composer

Comment: yes, that really helped me, but I have one more question, I'm displaying the count inside a bootstrap badge, I would like the badge to be hidden if the count is 0 (zero) how can I achieve that inside my AppServiceProvider file?

Comment: @if({$value->total)<span class="amos-badge">{{$value->total}}</span> @endif

Comment: yes, I also have another question that I posted yesterday, if you can help I will appreciate, here is my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041475/how-can-i-preview-data-and-edit-before-submitting-to-the-database-in-registratio)